# Basic list checker

Tags: python

I want to create a `list`, then enter an `int`, which will then add the `int` amount of strings to a `list`,then print it. So far so good:

```
list = []
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while number > 0:
    list.append(str(raw_input("Enter a word: ")))
    number = number - 1    
print list
```

However, how do I make it a little more advanced so that you cannot add the same string twice to the list?

Answer (score 4):

You can keep a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of all the strings seen, only adding a string and if it has not been seen before, you don't need to keep a count variable either, you can loop until `len(data) != number`:

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
seen = set()
data = []
while len(data) != number:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
    if inp not in seen:
        data.append(inp)   
        seen.add(inp)
```

If the order was irrelevant you could just use a set altogether as sets cannot have dupes:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))   
data = set()
while len(data) != number:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
    data.add(inp)
```

Comment: I feel you could avoid the use of set here

Comment: @VigneshKalai, so you think an `O(n)`  lookup would be better?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why not just lists it does the same thing right http://pastebin.com/MTaPkpHt I know searching in `sets` are faster but did not think there was a need to create a set[memory space] just for that

Comment: @VigneshKalai, nope,  `x in set -> 0(1)` `x in list -> O(n)`, for a problem like the OP's then of course a list is probably good enough but you I don't answer a question presuming the OP is always going to be dealing with a list with a few items and when you are dealing with large amounts of data using sets can make a monumental difference.

Comment: if that's the case take my upvote and can you show any links pertaining to that

Comment: @VigneshKalai, time  `[i in st for i in range(10000000)]` where st is a set of the same range and `[i in l for i in range(10000000)]`where l is `list(range(10000000))`, you might want to have a coffee for the second one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check for whether the list already contain the entered string or not before appending. And don't use in-built keywords as variable names.

```
list_ = []
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while number > 0:
    x = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
    if not x in list_:
        list_.append(x)
        number = number - 1    
    else:
        print "Word is already available"
print list_
```

Comment: `number = number - 1` should probably be inside the `if` clause.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
mylist = []
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
while number > 0:
    mystring = str(raw_input("Enter a word: "))
    if mystring not in mylist:
        mylist.append(mystring)
        number = number - 1
    else:
        print('Choose different string')
        next
print mylist
```

and try to avoid build-in function as variable name. Built-in functions are

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html